# Conditional formatting range of cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Hey sorry for the noob question. So I'm trying to create a formula that will turn a square green based on the text in a range of cells. I managed to get it to work for a single cell with "=$A3="Bob"". But I'd like to be able to check from A3-D6 so if Bob is typed into any of those squares then A11, for example, will turn green, is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `$`.

Comment: That would just check A3 though, not A3-D6 right?

Comment: Oh... misread the question. Try `=COUNTIF($A$3:$D$6,"Bob")>0`.

Comment: Worked a charm, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen explained, you can use the "COUNTIF" formula to count the number of times the if condition is met in a range of cells.

In your example pass "`=COUNTIF($A$3:$D$6,"Bob")>0`" as the condition to check in the conditional formatting of the range where the square lives.

---

#### References:

- [COUNTIF(range, criterion)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)